# Building PoDoFo but .lib file is not created

Tags: c++, linker, .lib, podofo

PoDoFo is a C++ library that is used to manipulate PDF files. I'm trying to use PoDoFo in one of my projects but I'm getting Linker errors because I do not have the .lib file.

I'm following the instructions on the readme.html when you download from http://podofo.sourceforge.net/download.html. I just want to use the library, however, it is not generating a .lib file to go with the .dll and I'm stumped as to why. I tried setting the PODOFO_BUILD_STATIC=TRUE and PODOFO_BUILD_SHARED=FALSE but that does not seem to do anything.

I was able to successfully build and compile it, it created the libpodofo.dll, an include directory and a lib directory which contains libpodofo.a and libpdofo.dll.a. As I understand it, the .a files are static files used for linking but do not work in Windows. I also tried to build my own .lib file by following some instructions and using the dll however that did not work either. I really want to use this library and I know I'm so close, what am I missing?

Comment: I'm guessing you've compiled with gcc which uses `.a` files for libraries, if you want `.lib` files compile with visual studio instead

Comment: Am I not able to create .lib files with cmake and mingw?

Comment: If you're using mingw why do you need lib files?

Comment: Interesting... I thought Mingw was supposed to compile the files into a windows usable format, meaning a .lib and .dll as opposed to .o and .a files for Linux, where am I not understanding? 

I compiled it on Visual Studio and finally was able to create the .lib file! I brought it into the project and am getting unresolved external symbols which leads me to believe the file may be corrupt?

Comment: I don't think it's a corruption error, but I will try to figure out what's happening because referencing the .lib file should fix the external symbols error.

Comment: Are you using mingw in your project? You can't mix compilers with c++ code which is why you get unresolved symbols

Comment: So I guess Mingw and Visual Studio compilers are different. I was able to compile it and use it in Visual Studio, now I want to use it in my other application as a standalone library. As far as I know, I only need the .h and .lib files. When I try to compile, it complains about unresolved external symbols on 2 objects, even tho it's the same file that compiles successfully in the version above

Comment: As expected, creating another project WITHIN the PoDoFo application allows my application to run and function, however, when I try to use it in an external application using the .h and .lib files, it errors out with the linker errors above, what gives? Please help me clear up my understanding.

Comment: At a guess you're missing some `#define` which tells podofo which symbols to look for

Comment: Here is a snippet from their documentation on an example file: [link](https://github.com/podofo/podofo/blob/master/examples/helloworld/helloworld.cpp)
nothing out of the ordinary. Just frustrating because I really want to know what's going on.